# Update json data in oracle sql

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle10g

This is my json data in one of the oracle sql columns "jsoncol" in a table named "jsontable"

```
{
  "Company": [
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "123"
      },
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Id": 999
    },
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "456"
      },
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Id": 888
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking for an `UPDATE` query to update all the value of "Name" with a new value based on a particular "Id" value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: The version 10g is very ancient, and suspicious if it supports any of the JSON related functions or properties ...

Comment: If you are looking for **update**, why does your question title say **retrieve**?

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 19, you can use `JSON_MERGEPATCH`:

```sql
UPDATE jsontable j
SET   jsoncol = JSON_MERGEPATCH(
                  jsoncol,
                  (
                    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                             KEY 'Company'
                             VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                                     CASE id
                                     WHEN 999
                                     THEN JSON_MERGEPATCH(
                                            json,
                                            '{"Name":"DEF"}'
                                          )
                                     ELSE json
                                     END
                                     FORMAT JSON
                                     RETURNING CLOB
                                   )
                             FORMAT JSON
                             RETURNING CLOB
                             )
                    FROM   jsontable jt
                           CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
                             jt.jsoncol,
                             '$.Company[*]'
                             COLUMNS(
                               json VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$',
                               id   NUMBER PATH '$.Id'
                             )
                           )
                    WHERE  jt.ROWID = j.ROWID
                  )
                )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE jsontable (
  jsoncol CLOB CHECK (jsoncol IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO jsontable (jsoncol)
VALUES ('{
  "Company": [
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "123"
      },
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Id": 999
    },
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "456"
      },
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Id": 888
    }
  ]
}');
```

Then after the `UPDATE`, the table contains:

> | JSONCOL |
> | --- |
> | {"Company":[{"Info":{"Address":"123"},"Name":"DEF","Id":999},{"Info":{"Address":"456"},"Name":"XYZ","Id":888}]} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=357e1eeedec9c2ec106b2c3f8dc70a45)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use **REPLACE()** within **JSON_TABLE()** function in order to update the value of the ***Name***(from *ABC* to *DEF*) for a specific Id value(*999*)  such as

```
UPDATE jsontable jt0
   SET jsoncol = ( SELECT REPLACE(jsoncol,jt.name,'DEF') 
                     FROM jsontable j,
                          JSON_TABLE(jsoncol,
                                    '$' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$.Company[*]'
                                                COLUMNS(
                                                         name VARCHAR2 PATH '$.Name',
                                                         id   INT      PATH '$.Id' 
                                                        )
                                                )
                                     ) jt
                    WHERE jt.id = 999
                      AND j.id = jt0.id )
```

for the DB version prior to `19` provided that the identity values(**id**) of the table and of the JSON values are unique throughout the table and each individual JSON value, respectively.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfba7da7cf71459c2813de874e76d0b6)</kbd>

Comment: This does not work due to multiple issues: 1) there is no correlation between rows in the `UPDATE` and rows in the nested `SELECT`; 2) the nested `SELECT` can return multiple rows as there can be multiple `id = 999` matches; and 3) The `REPLACE` is not limited to the replacing only the relevant JSON value but will globally replace matched substring. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dcc2c16b347854753213a5f6bbf335cb)